# How should I manage short-term user preferences, to simplify data cleanup?

Tags: data-structures

When rolling out a new feature, sometimes it makes sense to notify the end user what it is, and give them an opportunity to provide feedback whether the software should get them to 'try something new' or 'put it off'.

[image: Gmail new feature, "Try it now", "Not now"]

In a cloud software, how should user preference data such as this be managed? A small piece of information would have to be stored to save the preference, but eventually, it becomes irrelevant. (The old way is phased out.) The simple thing to do is just leave that data there. After all, it doesn't take much space.

Eventually, as more features and changes come and go, and more messages are added, dismissed, and removed; there would be many items in the data storage that is no longer used, and there would be cost in the form of programmer hours in preserving or separating that data.

Are there coding and software maintenance patterns that would make sense to get rid of old data structures along with removal of old features? Is there a common solution to this data cleanup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the version that phases out the old way, I'd add code to delete the obsolete data.  In the next version, I'd delete the code to delete the data. Hopefully this doesn't happen too often.

---

As an alternative, store your config data with an expiration date and update the expiration every time that particular bit of data is used.  Anything that's older than 6 months can probably be deleted.

---

Alternative #3 is to ignore the problem and hope it never comes back to haunt you.  I'm not a fan of this, but in some situations it's the right answer.

Comment: +1 for admitting that ignoring the problem sometimes is the right decision.

Comment: +1 In your second option the "probably" is very important, unless you include "read" in "use" ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the meta-data about what the features and their options are, and link the preferences to them.  Once you have done that, then when the options are eliminated it's a simple script to remove irrelevant preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to just stick a cookie on the user's machine with a short expiration.  When you kill the setting, remove the code that handles it.

This solution has numerous disadvantages, but it does removes data cleanup concerns.